# Boundary of $M_rp$ not equal to the sphere of radius $r$ at $p$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My problem is to find a metric space in which the boundary of $M_rp$, where $M_rp = \{q \in M: d(p, q) < r \}$, is not equal to the sphere of radius $r$ at $p, \{x \in M: d(x, p) = r\}$. Furthermore, does the boundary have to be contained in the sphere?

I have some intuition that I can just construct a discrete metric space with a finite number of points, but I don't know how to formulate this thinking into words. Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: What is $M_rp$?

Comment: Sorry, edited OP!

Answer (score 1):

Closed balls are closed, and open balls are open, and that answers your containment question.

As you suspected, a discrete space answers your other question. Let $S$ be a subset of any discrete space (finite or not). What is the boundary of $S$?